# Need to auto increment but multiple entries have to have the same int assigned using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, database-design

I was about to create my tables when I noticed, sh!t. I have no field to group similar entries (that is the main purpose of this table lol). The idea is, there is a family that has signed up and I want to group them. So when I pull out data, I can assign prices to the family as a whole.

```
gp_ID    customer    leader_Of_Group
  1         Turk           yes
  1         JD              no
  1         Sarah           no
  1         Felina          no
  2         John            no
  2         Manny           no
  2         Jaden          yes
```

***note - simplified table for readability**

My problem is, I don't know how i'm going to achieve the gp_ID. I am confident primary keys don't allow duplicate values so, i'm stumped at the moment.

The gp_ID will be entered automatically, I just don't know how to increment after each family has signed up. Furthermore, there is functionality where my client can select which passengers to group.

I'm not sure how to go about setting up this table or how to query it in a way that each family will increment appropriately. My only thought so far is finding out the gp_ID based on the latest entry and increment, and even then I don't know how to go about doing that or if i'm on the right track. Also, would an auto increment field be necessary too? Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you create another column with auto increment so now there is a unique ID to each person. IF the case is that you have another table that has the unique ID of each person. Just make a primary key, the forign key to that ID in the other table.

Comment: What database engine are you using? The MyISAM and BDB engines support composite primary keys with an autoincrement on the secondary column - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: What is the purpose of gp_id? Is the ID used anywhere else, or is it just a `hash` to group similar rows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are facing an issue because you really have two entities.  One of the those entities is the group and the other is the group members.

Your process for adding members to a group should be:

1. Add a row to the `Groups` table.  This would have an auto-incrementing id.
2. Add rows to the `GroupMembers` table, identifying the group using the previous id.

Voila!  The groups will be well identified.  The `Groups` table itself could have columns such as:

- GroupId (auto-incremented id)
- Name for the group
- Creation date
- Leader_MemberId

The latter would be a way of ensuring that each group has exactly one leader, without having to write a trigger to enforce this constraint.

Comment: +1 although maybe it would be best not to have the LEADER_MEMBERID field on the GROUPS table, rather create a 3rd table, GROUPLEADERS, with the leader indicated there, a well as an EFFDT column (to account for changes to who the leader of each group is at various dates). That way you could query to see who the leader was of a given group/family as of 1/1/13, 5/1/13, etc. rather than just as of today.

Comment: @BrianDeMilia . . . That is also a good idea, if the leaders are a slowly changing dimensions.

Comment: @BrianDeMilia what you say also is good too. I never would have thought of that. I'll have to talk it up with the client. It's not stated in the scope to query leaders from given date range. But if I know clients right, they'll change their minds no doubt lol